# How to use array items as parameter for API call

Tags: javascript, arrays, api

I am currently trying to log out the names and ID of a various items for a video game using an array which holds the ID of each item.

Currently I have the following.

```js
const URL =
  "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=";
const items = ["4151", "2"];

items.map(item => {
  fetch(`${URL}${item}`)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(({ item: { id, name } }) => console.log(`${id}: + ${name}`));
});
```

I should be getting `4151: Abyssal Whip` as a format for each item, but it isnt working. I have done this in the past using a cryptocurrency api, but I cant get it to work here, and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Can you mention the error you're getting? Is it a `CORS policy` error?

Comment: Check your browser console or error logs and see what errors are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure its a typical `CORS` policy error. Here's how I managed to fetch the data. The `heroku` API enables cross-origin requests to anywhere.

```
const items = ["4151", "2"];
const proxyUrl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/",
  targetUrl =
    "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_oldschool/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=";
items.map((item) => {
  fetch(proxyUrl + targetUrl + item)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then(({ item: { id, name } }) => console.log(`${id}: + ${name}`));
});
```

Comment: Hey @ETHan, any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Some more detail would help. If you open dev tools and look at console output when hitting the API, you might be getting an error... maybe a Mixed-Content error? The runescape API is returning from an HTTP connection. If you are requesting from an HTTPS connection, it will not allow the resource to be delivered. Otherwise, your code should run (but the `+`) won't be necessary because you're using template literals.